# custom user login with ASP.NET using SQL and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, authentication

I've been working on a ASP.NET application and I've managed to create a Login and register webpage linked to a SQL Database using C# as server-side code.
**Problem:**
I couldn't find a good method to keep a user logged in while opening different pages, 
What is the best method to do this but then 100% customizable, preferably tot using "Logincontrols".

Thanks for your time!

Comment: [ASP.Net Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)?

Comment: WebForms or MVC?  What version of the .NET framework are you using?  Here is a Microsoft tutorial covering the subject.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The user is tied to a `Session`. All pages have that property available. It's an `HttpSessionState` object, and this is where you can house the logged in user information. Now, you can encapsulate a lot of that work by building a `User` class that has `static` accessors that actually pull data out of session. For example:

```
public static class User
{
    public static bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(session["LoggedInUser"]);
        }
    }

    public static string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return session["LoggedInUser"];
        }
    }

    public static bool Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        // login (i.e. verify the user name and password

        // build some kind of session indicator
        HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUser"] = userName;

        return true;
    }

    public static void Logout()
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticated) { return; }
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    }
}
```

and so now from the pages you can just do stuff like this:

```
User.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the HttpSession, storing the email of the user logged. After that, in each page you have to check if it's not null. I post an example

```
public class SessionProvider
{

    public static void Put(string key, string value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }
    public static void PutObject(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    public static void Delete(string key)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(key);
    }

    public static string Get(string key)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null)
            return null;
        else
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString();
    }

    public static object GetObject(string key)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    public static void Abandon()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    }

}
```